# Are there simpler ways to do traffic shaping in linux besides tc?

Tags: ip, tcpip, qos, traffic-shaping

I read [lartc](http://lartc.org/) but I don't feel I need such a complicated solution for simple needs.
One of such simple use cases is to limit a specific process' available bandwidth, upstream or downstream. How can I run wget or firefox constrained to 50 kb/s download speed without using iptaables and qdiscs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

us [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle). sample cmdline:

```
trickle -d 10 wget http://noc.gts.pl/50mb.gts
```

you can repalce wget with any other command. and btw - wget has built in bandwidth limiting option: --limit-rate=amount - so it does not require any external tools to slow it down.

Answer (score 3):

Wget has built in bandwidth control with the --limit-rate option.
Shorewall also offers a nicer interface to traffic shaping, as does wondershaper.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use Squid-Cache as your local proxy and have that software manage the limiting/shaping?  Any Squid gurus out there?