# Find slow dns address resolving for test purposes

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to find an address that resolves realy slowly to test dns resolving error handling. Or if I can simulate a slow dns address resolving it will be also fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any one around here maintains a list of slow DNS servers.  You could simulate slow DNS resolution by setting up [traffic shaping](https://serverfault.com/a/154518/50647) to an existing name server, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`slodns`](https://github.com/brennentsmith/slodns) does this (defaults to delaying answers by 1s).  Found it via [this workshop explaining how to troubleshoot](https://github.com/goldshtn/linux-tracing-workshop/blob/master/node-slowdns.md), using `gethostlatency`.